# Почему путем сложения и вычитания получаются разные цифры?

Tags: javascript, математика

Насколько я знаю, `2 + 2 + 2` это то же самое, что и `2 * 3`. Результат получается точно такой же. Почему в JS не так?

```js
let result = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   result += 0.2; //сложение
};
console.log(result);

console.log(0.2 * 50); //умножение
```

Comment: очевидно, складывание происходит в недесятичной системе https://learn.javascript.ru/number

Comment: С целыми числами всё ок, а вот с числами с плавающей точкой - всё не так очевидно увы